# Getting a series of Excel Listbox Controls to Work Together Seamlessly

Tags: excel, vba, listbox-control

I'm developing an application in Excel that allows the user to set up their PLC IO configuration by choosing from a large list of different PLC modules. Modules are chosen by selecting, in order, Manufacturer, Device Family, Device Type, and Module Name. Each attribute selections corresponds to a different ListBox control. The ListFillRange of each ListBox is controlled by the previous ListBox. For example, when I click the first ListBox to choose my Manufacturer, my VBA code clears the previous Device Family ListFillRange, and repopulates it with all Device Families from the newly selected Manufacturer. Also, each ListBox uses a specific range as it's ListFillRange. It might be the case that I can populate each ListBox selection list more directly using VBA but I haven't been able to figure out how to do this. Each ListBox uses the ListBox_Click() event to run its code.  The issues I'm having are the following.

- It seems that when one ListBox clears the ListFillRange of the next ListBox, it triggers the code of the next ListBox to run and this often causes a "Run-time error '1004': Clear method of Range class failed."
- When the code doesn't error out it often resizes the next ListBox to the point that it can't be read.

Below is an example of the code run when the Device Family ListBox is clicked. It will clear the Module Types List Fill Range and repopulate it with all Module Types from the newly selected Device Family.

```
Private Sub ListBox2_Click()
Dim row As Integer
row = 2
Dim totalRows As Integer
Dim ModuleTypes(30) As Variant
Dim ArrayIndex As Integer
ArrayIndex = 0
totalRows = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Tables").Cells(2, 5).Value

'Clear the Module Type selection list on the PLC Module Data Sheet.
'ThisWorkbook.Sheets("PLC Module Data").Range("C2:C500").Clear

'Clear the Table Name search result list on the PLC Module Data Sheet.
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("PLC Module Data").Range("I2:L500").Clear 

'Search the Table Name sheet for all entries fromm the selected MFG and with the selected Family and paste them onto the PLC Module Data Sheet.
For i = 2 To totalRows
    If (ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Tables").Cells(i, 2).Value = ListBox1.Value) And (ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Tables").Cells(i, 3).Value = ListBox2.Value) Then
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("PLC Module Data").Cells(row, 9).Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Tables").Cells(i, 1).Value
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("PLC Module Data").Cells(row, 10).Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Tables").Cells(i, 2).Value
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("PLC Module Data").Cells(row, 11).Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Tables").Cells(i, 3).Value
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("PLC Module Data").Cells(row, 12).Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Tables").Cells(i, 4).Value
    row = row + 1
End If
Next I

'Form an array of all unique Module Types within the Table search results list.
For i = 2 To ThisWorkbook.Sheets("PLC Module Data").Cells(2, 13).Value
If ArrayTest(ModuleTypes, ThisWorkbook.Sheets("PLC Module Data").Cells(i, 12).Value) Then
    ModuleTypes(ArrayIndex) = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("PLC Module Data").Cells(i, 12).Value
    ArrayIndex = ArrayIndex + 1
End If
Next i

'Copy the ModuleTypes Array into the Module Type selection list on the PLC Module Data Sheet.
For i = 0 To UBound(ModuleTypes)
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("PLC Module Data").Cells(2 + i, 3).Value = ModuleTypes(i)
Next i

'Clear the Temp search result list on the PLC Module Data Sheet.
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("PLC Module Data").Range("U2:X500").Clear
```

If anyone knows how I can get around the issues I listed above and get the set of ListBoxes to work seamlessly together, it would be very much appreciated. thanks.

Comment: I don't know if you need it to be like that, but in any case you could use dependent drop down list from data validation. You could read [this](https://trumpexcel.com/dependent-drop-down-list-in-excel/) to know how to build em. At the end they will select the items from cells and there will be no errors.

Comment: In [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38512290/in-vba-in-excel-differentiating-between-a-listbox-changing-programatically-vs) Question the author also faces problems with unexpected events firing. The solution is to set a "flag" to stop the other boxes from updating.

Comment: @L8n I'm pretty new to this stuff so I'm not entirely sure what is going on in the code in your link. It seems like a property is defined under the scope of the worksheet containing the forms, which is then used to determine if the checkboxes were ticked manually or by code. Would I define a similar property and then having all my ListBox_Click() events check to see if the flag is set and exit the sub if it is?

Comment: Also, even if my ListBox_Click() routines are being executed by other routines, I'm still not exactly sure why they always error out on the lines of code that clear cells and give the "Clear method of Range class failed" message. Does this have to do with the fact the cells being cleared are on a different sheet than the ListBox form and something about the way the code is executing is not allowing the other sheet to be selected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the feedback, everyone. I got them working using the flag method mentioned in the comments.